# Return rows in a table where several columns are equal

Tags: sql, date, join, select

I have the below table:

[image: Table]

I'm trying to write some SQL to return `Row ID`s (in pairs) where the below is true for two given rows:

- `Item` is equal
- `Name` is equal
- `Measure` is equal
- `Dates` overlap

So far what I have tried to do is use `SELECT`, `WHERE` & `GROUP BY` to return `Row ID`s (I'm aware this lacks the date functionality at present):

```
SELECT rowid FROM techtest GROUP BY Customer, Product, Measure;
```

However this returns individual `Row ID`s instead of pairs. For example what I hope to get as a return is `Row ID` 1 & 2 together, as they meet all of the criteria listed.

How would I go about writing this to return a list of pairs of rows which meet the criteria listed?

Comment: Your question confuses me. You want to select 1, 2 and 3 together because item, name and measure is equal and dates overlap, but how do you expect to return them? 4, 5 and 6 also meet your  criteria. Do you want 2 rows with 1 column saying `1, 2, 3` and `4, 5, 6` respectively? How do you want them grouped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution to generate the expected resultset would be to self-JOIN the table:

```
SELECT t1.row_id, t2.row_id
FROM mytable t1
INNER JOIN mytable t2 
    ON  t1.item    = t2.item
    AND t1.name    = t2.name
    AND t1.measure = t2.measure
    AND t1.begin_date  <= t2.expiry_date 
    AND t1.expiry_date >= t2.begin_date
    AND t1.row_id  < t2.row_id
```

The logic lies in the `ON` conditions of the `JOIN` :

- `t1.begin_date  <= t2.expiry_date AND t1.expiry_date >= t2.begin_date` represents the date range overlap condition (see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap) for more details) - depending on your RDBMS, there might be more straight-forward solutions available
- `t1.row_id  < t2.row_id` avoids duplicates in the results like (`1, 2`, `2, 1`)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if understood correctly, but this shows how you could proceed:

```
create table trash ( 
 id integer, 
 ticket text, 
 name text);

insert into trash values(1,'ticket','name1'),(2,'ticket','name1');
insert into trash values(3,'billet','name2'),(4,'billet','name2');

select * from trash 

 ;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
+------+----------+--------+
| id   | ticket   | name   |
|------+----------+--------|
| 1    | ticket   | name1  |
| 2    | ticket   | name1  |
| 3    | billet   | name2  |
| 4    | billet   | name2  |
+------+----------+--------+

select distinct(array[least(trash.id,t1.id), greatest(trash.id, t1.id)]) 
from (select * from trash) t1 
left join trash on t1.ticket=trash.ticket 
and t1.name=trash.name 
and trash.id != t1.id;   

+---------+
| array   |
|---------|
| [3, 4]  |
| [1, 2]  |
+---------+
```